# Rational point on a right angled triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rational-numbers, geometric-topology

[image]

Consider a right-angled triangle with vertex co-ordinates $(0,0), (a,0)$ and $(0,b)$. The length of the hypotenuse is $c$. Moreover, $a, b$ and $c$ are positive integers i.e., $(a,b,c)$ is a **Pythagorean triple**.

Following are my conjectures in the increasing order of difficulty.

**Conjecture 1**: There exists a rational point $(r,0)$ at a rational distance from $(0,b)$, such that $r > 0$, $r \neq a$.

**Conjecture 2**: There exists a rational point $(r,0)$ at a rational distance from $(0,b)$, such that $0< r < a$.

**Conjecture 3**: There exists an **infinite** number of rational points $(r, 0)$ at a rational distance from $(0,b)$, such that $0< r < a$.

**Conjecture 4a**: For **any** two rational numbers $0< r_1 < r_2 < a$, there exists a rational point $(r,0)$ at a rational distance from $(0,b)$, such that $0< r_1 < r < r_2 < a$.

**Conjecture 4b**: For **any** two rational numbers $0< r_1 < r_2 < a$, there exists an **infinite** number of rational points $(r,0)$ at a rational distance from $(0,b)$, such that $0< r_1 < r < r_2 < a$.

Note that conjecture 4a implies 4b.

**My question**: Are the above conjectures known to be true / false ?

**Note**: In all the above conjectures, I want the existence of the point $(r,0)$ on the $x$-axis, for both cases $a > b$ and $a < b$.

**Motivation**: An affirmative answer to the above questions will help me generate certain fractals in a clean way.

**A known fact**: The set of points with rational distances to the vertices of a given triangle with sides of rational length is everywhere dense [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INtLM.jpg).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INtLM.jpg) J.H.J. Almering, Rational quadrilaterals, Indag. Math. 25 (1963) 192–199.

Comment: For conjecture 1 and 2: just choose $r =\frac{ b^2}{a}$, and the hypotenuse will be $\frac{ bc}{a}$.

Comment: For conjecture 3:  Choose two integers $m$ and $n$, so that $\frac{b}{a}<\frac{2mn}{m^2-n^2}$. Use $r =\frac{b(m^2-n^2)}{2mn}$ and the hypotenuse will be $\frac{b(m^2+n^2)}{2mn}$.

Comment: @RicardoCruz For your choice of $r$, if $b>a$, then $r=\frac{b^2}a > b > a$. The choice works for conjecture 1 but needs more work for conjecture 2.

Comment: Yes, @peterwhy, you are right. I assumed from the figure that $b<a$.

Comment: I want the answers for both cases: a > b and a < b. I have added this clarification above.

Comment: For conjectures 1 and 2: $r=\frac{|a^2 - b^2|}{2a}$ works for both $a < b$ and $a > b$. The hypotenuse is $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2a}$

Comment: For conjecture 3: $r=\frac{b|m^2-n^2|}{2mn}$ works, because there are infinitely many $m,n$ satisfying $\frac{2mn}{|m^2-n^2|} > \frac{b}{a}$ for both cases $a > b$ and $a < b$. For example: start with $m=a$, $n=b$ and then $m=a-1$, $n=b$ and so on.

Comment: For conjectures 4a, 4b: We need to prove that, for any $0 < r_1 < r_2 < a$ there exists one pair (or infinitely many pairs) $(m, n)$ such that $r_1 < \frac{b|m^2-n^2|}{2mn} < r_2$.

Comment: For a generalization, please look at my next question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507436/rational-point-on-two-overlapping-right-angled-triangles