# Rational point on two overlapping right angled triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rational-numbers, geometric-topology

[image]

This question is a generalization of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506843/rational-point-on-a-right-angled-triangle).

Consider the two right-angled triangles shown in the above picture. The first triangle has vertex co-ordinates $(0,0), (a,0)$ and $(0,b_1)$. The second triangle has vertex co-ordinates $(0,0), (a,0)$ and $(0,b_2)$. The length of the hypotenuses of these two triangles are $c_1$ and $c_2$ respectively. Moreover, $a, b_1, b_2, c_1$ and $c_2$ are positive integers i.e., $(a,b_1,c)$ and $(a,b_2,c)$ are **Pythagorean triples**.

Following are my conjectures in the increasing order of difficulty.

**Conjecture 1**: There exists a rational point $(r,0)$ at a rational distance from $(0,b_1)$ **and** $(0,b_2)$, such that $r > 0$, $r \neq a$.

**Conjecture 2**: There exists a rational point $(r,0)$ at a rational distance from $(0,b_1)$ and $(0,b_2)$, such that $0< r < a$.

**Conjecture 3**: There exists an **infinite** number of rational points $(r, 0)$ at a rational distance from $(0,b_1)$ and $(0,b_2)$, such that $0< r < a$.

**Conjecture 4**: For **any** two rational numbers $0< r_1 < r_2 < a$, there exists a rational point $(r,0)$ at a rational distance from $(0,b_1)$ and $(0,b_2)$, such that $0< r_1 < r < r_2 < a$.

**My question**: Are the above conjectures known to be true / false ?

**Note**: In all the above conjectures, I would like to know the existence / non-existence of the point $(r,0)$ on the $x$-axis, for all the three cases: (i) $a < b_1$, (ii) $b_1 < a < b_2$ and (iii) $a > b_2$.

**Motivation**: An affirmative answer to the above questions will help me generate certain fractals in a clean way.

Comment: Have you tested your conjectures in the case $a=12$, $b_1=5,b_2=9$?

Comment: Conjecture 3 should be true, since it boils down to proving that there infinite triples of the form $m,m+b_1^2,m+b_2^2$ of rational squares. Similar problems are well known to be related to rational points on elliptic curves, for instance the problem of finding three rational squares in arithmetic progression: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/3squarearithprog.pdf